# Compiler error: passing const object as ‘this’ argument of a method discards qualifiers

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error

error: passing ‘const Polilinea’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Polilinea::NumeroPuntos()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

and I don't know what's wrong with my code, this is the header file and class file, in my class notes the syntax in the examples is exactly like in my code, but when I compile it, the compiler complains to me that this is not correct, my solution is not to declare const in the methods, but I would like to know what causes the error.
This is the header file:

```
#ifndef PUNTO
#define PUNTO
#ifndef POLILINEA
#define POLILINEA

using namespace std;

class Punto{
private:
  double x, y;
public:
  Punto(double abcisa, double ordenada);
  bool operator == (const Punto otro);
  double GetX();
  double GetY();
};

class Polilinea{
private:
  Punto *puntos; // vector con los puntos de la linea
  int num; //numero de puntos

  //funciones privadas de ayuda para los metodos publicos
  void ReservaMemoria(int numero_puntos);
  void LiberaMemoria();
  void CopiaPuntos(const Polilinea & otra);
public:
  Polilinea(int numero_puntos);//constructor por defecto
  Polilinea(const Polilinea & otra); //operador de copia
  ~Polilinea(); // destructor

  //sobrecarga de operadores
  Polilinea & operator = (const Polilinea & otra);
  Punto operator [] (const int indice);
  bool operator == (const Polilinea & otra);
  bool operator != (const Polilinea & otra);
  friend Polilinea operator + (const Punto sumado);
  friend Polilinea operator + (const Punto sumado, const Polilinea & sumada);

  //auxiliares
  void SetNumPuntos(int numero);
  int NumeroPuntos();
};

#endif
#endif
```

The cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include "polilinea.h"

using namespace std;

Punto :: Punto(double abcisa = 0.0, double ordenada = 0.0): x(abcisa), y(ordenada){};

double Punto :: GetX(){
  return x;
};

double Punto :: GetY(){
  return y;
};

bool Punto :: operator == (Punto otro){
  bool iguales;
  if((x == otro.GetX()) && (y == otro.GetY()))
    iguales = true;
  else iguales = false;
};

Polilinea & Polilinea :: operator = (const Polilinea & otra){
  if(this != &otra){
    Polilinea temp(otra.NumeroPuntos());

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
      temp[i] = otra[i];

    return (*this);
  };
};

Punto Polilinea :: operator [] (const int indice){
  return (puntos[indice]);
};

int Polilinea :: NumeroPuntos(){
  return num;
}
```

Comment: **TL;DR:** This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 1):

> error: passing ‘const Polilinea’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Polilinea::NumeroPuntos()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

As the error says - you are calling `NumeroPuntos` on a const reference to `Polilinea`. As `NumeroPuntos` is not a const function, the compiler is warning you that it may change the value, which is not normally allowed (except you are using -fpermissive which tells the compiler to allow it).

The easiest method to fix this is to mark your `NumeroPuntos` method as `const`:

```
int NumeroPuntos() const;
```

Comment: any other function that doesn't modify the object should be `const` also, e.g. ` bool operator == (const Punto otro);`

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain it to you in simple words.

`otra` in the method `Polilinea & Polilinea :: operator =` is a const reference. This means that:

1. `otra` cannot change
2. you cannot call any method on `otra` which is not const

You call `NumeroPuntos` on `otra`. `NumeroPuntos` is not const and the compiler tells you it's not correct. `NumeroPuntos` does not change your object, but the compiler "is not smart enough to know it". You have to tell him that `NumeroPuntos` does not change anything. You can do it by adding const to the method declaration. Like this:

```
int Polilinea :: NumeroPuntos() const;
```

Both in the header and cpp files.

If you do it, everything will be ok. The compiler will allow to call `NumeroPuntos` on `otra`. `otra` is const and `NumeroPuntos` is const too.

You should make all your methods which do not change your object const. This is true in general.